Excel - how to continuously count cells till the same value is reached
In excel, I have events that happen every day with differing frequencies. A column (B) with a formula keeps track of the event number, starting over at the first event with a #1 when the date in column A changes, like so:



Date
Event #
Day Total




10/30/2024
1



10/30/2024
2



10/30/2024
3



10/30/2024
4



10/30/2024
5
5


10/31/2024
1



10/31/2024
2



10/31/2024
3
3


11/1/2024
1



11/1/2024
2



11/1/2024
3



11/1/2024
4
4



I'd like a formula that:

Counts the number of events for each day, i.e total of 5 for 10/30, 3 for 10/31 and 4 for 11/1. The easiest way to do this might be to count till the value 1 (re)appears. But then keep counting till 1 appears again.
Then I'd like to see max, min, average, median frequencies per day. If we accomplish the first requirement, this could easily be done in a helper column C by putting the daily totals there first.
But I'd like the max, min, etc. stats to automatically update as new data is entered for 11/2/24 and beyond, so the range/array should keep expanding.

Tried various countif, index, match, etc. combinations with no success. Counting till the first 1 is encountered is elementary. Can't figure out how to keep doing it down the range without looping, let alone expanding the range automatically as new data is added to the column. The simplest might be a do-while loop, but I don't know any VBA. Thanks in advance.

Sounds like you need a pivot table. I can't check because I'm not going to click that link

Could you insert in the post sample data table in Markdown and your attempted formulas

Assuming there is no Excel Constraints as per the post tags, one could try using the following:


=LET(
     a, MAP(B2:B13,LAMBDA(x,SUM(N(x:B2=x)))),
     b, XLOOKUP(B2:B13,B2:B13,a,,,-1),
     HSTACK(a, IF(a<b,"",b)))


And if you want the counts and the max of counts to show whenever newer data is added, then could use one of the following based on the version of MS365 you are in:
• Using the help of TRIMRANGE() feature:
=LET(
     a, DROP(B.:.B,1),
     b, MAP(a,LAMBDA(x,SUM(N(x:B2=x)))),
     c, XLOOKUP(a,a,b,,,-1),
     HSTACK(b, IF(b<c,"",c)))


• Or without the use of TRIMRANGE()
=LET(
     a, B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(2,1/(B:B<>""))),
     b, MAP(a,LAMBDA(x,SUM(N(x:B2=x)))),
     c, XLOOKUP(a,a,b,,,-1),
     HSTACK(b, IF(b<c,"",c)))


A simple solution for the bullet 2 using AGGREGATE() :


=VSTACK({"Min","Max","Average","Median"},
 AGGREGATE({5,4,1,12},7,DROP(C2#,,1)))


Change orientation per your preference by changing the separators:

=HSTACK({"Min";"Max";"Average";"Median"},
 AGGREGATE({5;4;1;12},7,DROP(C2#,,1)))



Hey buddy. Solid answer as always. That match function though is something I've wrested with quite a bit. In cases when we're sure the last value in column should be a number, this is astronimically faster... (just make sure to use big number!)
=MATCH(9.99E+99,B:B,1)

@pgSystemTester Sir, sure sir, I will do that going forward. Thanks for the heads up as always.

You're welcome. I have wasted WAAAAAAY too much of my life experimenting with best way to find last row. Your approach will always work, but the speed difference is enough where it's worth considering possibilities. Take care.

@pgSystemTester Sir, yes, alright understood now. Saw your vba post on that as well.

@pgSystemTester The maximum positive number that Excel allows to enter is 9.99999999999999E+307. But it's less than the maximum positive double number. To get the maximum use the sum of 9.99999999999999E+307 and 7,97693134E+307. More digits can be specified in the last number.

Using this number did not change performance, thus IMHO, the most optimal formula to find the last row is: =LAMBDA(xcol,LET(textVal,"",numVal,9.99999999999999E+307, useNumFirst,COUNT(xcol), firstSearchTerm,IF(useNumFirst,numVal,textVal), firstSearch,IFERROR(MATCH(firstSearchTerm,xcol,1),1),firstSrchRng,DROP(xcol,firstSearch),IF(COUNTA(firstSrchRng)=0,firstSearch,LET(secondSearchTerm,IF(useNumFirst,textVal,numVal),secondSearch,MATCH(secondSearchTerm,firstSrchRng,1)+firstSearch,IF(COUNTA(DROP(xcol,secondSearch))=0,secondSearch,XMATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(xcol),0,-1))))))

Parts two and three of your question are pretty basic once Part 1 is figured out. With the latest array functions, it's pretty easy to get a dynamic list like you have in column c. Mayukh Bhattacharya's answer does it but below is probably slightly better for performance.
Paste this into cell c2 and it will dynamically give you that.
=LET(dateCol,A:A,EventCol,B:B,iRng,SEQUENCE(COUNT(dateCol),1,ROW(),1),IF(INDEX(dateCol,iRng+1,1)=INDEX(dateCol,iRng,1),"",INDEX(EventCol,iRng,1)))

Answers that reference some place like row 2000 or 20k should be disregarded.


automatically update the range to last non-blank cell with XLOOKUP
get frequencies with COUNTIFS instead of looking at Event #
please adjust a2:a2000 to the match your dataset
format the first column (event date) in your preferred date format

=LET(
    last, XLOOKUP(TRUE, A2:A2000 <> "", A2:A2000, , , -1),
    dates, A2:last,
    counts, COUNTIFS(dates, dates),
    UNIQUE(HSTACK(dates, counts))
)

if GROUPBY is available,
=LET(
    last, XLOOKUP(TRUE, A2:A2000 <> "", A2:A2000, , , -1),
    dates, A2:last,
    GROUPBY(dates, dates, COUNT, 0, 0)
)

then use the result for calculations by using Spilled range operator, here with C3#:
=LET(
    freq, INDEX(C3#, , 2),
    VSTACK(
        {"Min", "Max", "Avg", "Median"},
        HSTACK(MIN(freq), MAX(freq), AVERAGE(freq), MEDIAN(freq))
    )
)



Assuming the dates in column A are always in order (which appears to be the case), and there are no blank cells within the date range, you could try the following dynamic array formula in cell B2 to spill the results for Event # and Day Total together:
=LET(
    rng, A2:INDEX(A:A,XMATCH(,A:A)-1),
    acc, rng=VSTACK(0,DROP(rng,-1)),
    num, SCAN(0,acc,LAMBDA(a,v,a*v+1)),
    HSTACK(num,IF(VSTACK(DROP(acc,1),0),"",num))
)


This method should remain relatively efficient, even with tens of thousands of rows of data.
Note: in this scenario, with the Date header in cell A1, the rng and acc variables could also be defined as follows:
=LET(
    rng, A1:INDEX(A:A,XMATCH(,A:A)-1),
    acc, DROP(rng,1)=DROP(rng,-1),
    ...
)


In cell C2 enter a 1
In cell C3 you can enter the formula

=IF(B3=B2,1+C2,1)

in  cell D2 enter the formula

=IF(C3=1,C2,"")

then just drag them down to the end.
You will have to manually enter the last figure in column D.

Thank you. I had done the first bit you're suggesting with =IF(B3<>B2,1,C2+1) which gives us column C, and we now also have the daily totals in D. I can simply auto-insert another 1 in 14B when this data gets auto-imported in from elsewhere daily because 14 is the first blank cell in B. That would get around the requirement to manually enter the last figure in D. But we still don't have the auto-expanding range. Looking to expand the range till the first blank cell in B, basically.

I would like to propose you the next solution where you need to enter the next date value only:

[B2]=IF(A2=A1,B1+1,1)
[D2]=LET(u,UNIQUE(Table1[Date]),HSTACK(u,MAP(u,LAMBDA(I,COUNTIF(Table1[Date],"="&I)))))
[H2]=LET(d,TAKE(D2#,,-1),VSTACK(MIN(d),MAX(d),AVERAGE(d),MEDIAN(d)))

Steps to do:

Create the data range entering the header, the first date, and the B2 formula.
Select A1 and press Ctrl+T to convert the range to the table.
Enter D2 formula.
Enter G2:G5 titles and H2 formula.

Then you only need to enter the next date value. Everything else will be updated automatically.

This is also an option:
=IF(B2:B13=MAXIFS(B2:B13,A2:A13,A2:A13),B2:B13,"")
